# How to stop Windows Media Player to play next song before current one ends

Tags: windows-media-player

When I have more than one song on my Windows Media Player playlist, it plays the next song on the list before, that the current song ends. It's like that it fades the next song in while fading the current out.

How can I make it play the song to the end before starting on the next one? It's very annoying when I listen to lectures etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Crossfading. Not sure what version you of Windows Media Player you have, so these instruction might be a little different for you.

Go to the View Menu, located along the top of the Windows Media Player Window and click Enhancements. Now choose Crossfading and Auto Volum Leveling. Then turn off Crossfading.

Comment: Thanks - it worked! For anyone having this problem: I had to switch to *Now Playing*-mode and then right-click anywhere on the screen to find the Enhancement-menu.